# Displaying a random string after each button press

Tags: android

Learning how to produce random numbers from arrays. The code will pick a random string during the `onCreate` method, but when the button is clicked there is no change to the string. Am I messing up the scope of my variables somehow? I really do not know what it wrong.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String[] qArray; //initialize qArray
private static final Random rgen = new Random(); //sets the new Random method to the keyword rgen

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    qArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.qArray); //grabs string array in the XML file

    String q = qArray[rgen.nextInt(qArray.length)];//generates a random index of qArray to set to q

    TextView question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question); //sets the TextView to "question"

    question.setText(q); //sets the text in "question" to q



}

public void onClick(View view){
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_click);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

                 /*This should do the same thing as onCreate but each time                          
                   the button is pressed. I think the error is here.*/

            String q = qArray[rgen.nextInt(qArray.length)];
            TextView question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
            question.setText(q);

           }
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you haven't set click listener on button properly you made onClick method which is never called . Also you are getting the references of view multiple times you should do it like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] qArray; //initialize qArray
    private static final Random rgen = new Random(); //sets the new Random     method to the keyword rgen

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        qArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.qArray); //grabs string array in the XML file

        String q = qArray[rgen.nextInt(qArray.length)];//generates a random index of qArray to set to q

        TextView question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question); //sets the TextView to "question"

        question.setText(q); //sets the text in "question" to q
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_click);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                 /*This should do the same thing as onCreate but each time                          
                   the button is pressed. I think the error is here.*/

                String q = qArray[rgen.nextInt(qArray.length)];
                question.setText(q);
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly it. As soon as I can, I'll accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to set the onClickListener in xml (in which case you don't need to set the listener in code), or you need to set the listener in onCreate.  Right now its being set in a function named onClick, which is never called.

Answer (score 0):

First, you never set the onClickListeren. You have a method which adds one, but you never call it. Move the code in the `onClick` method to your `onCreate` method. This will probably fix your problem.

If not, don't make your Random final and add this to your `@Override onClick()`:

`rgen = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());`

This will use a different seed every time